# Семантика работы VTable в языке C# и её расположение в среде CLR

Tags: c#, clr, спецификация

Хотелось бы узнать, если какой то гайд\статья\спецификация,которые бы описывали семантику работы **VTable** в языке C#.
Общее представление имеется,а именно тот факт,что таблица методов хранится в **Типе**(и у каждого типа она своя),но все же хочется услышать более продвинутую версию(начиная от лексем в метаданных,заканчивая флагами **NewSlot** / **ReuseSlot** и так далее).

Comment: Наличие VTable в C# не требуется стандартом и зависит от реализации. Текущая версия CLR использует таблицу виртуальных методов под капотом, но её наличие не гарантировано. Соответственно можно лишь подсмотреть в текущую имплементацию.

Comment: @VladD а как обстоят дела с хранением этой VTable ? Она находится в объекте типа(и каждый экземпляр этого типа,будет ссылаться на VTable в её типе,по аналогии статики) или же у каждого экземпляра класса присутствует?

Comment: Она одна на тип, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @VladD т.е. по сути так же,как и со статикой?(ну хранится в типе и доступна в единственном варианте для всех созданных экземпляров типа) ?

Comment: Ага. Вот тут есть ссылка на статью в MSDN, которая описывает лэйаут данных: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38551273/276994

Comment: Ещё нашлось вот это: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti

Comment: @VladD спасибо.У вас есть желание оформить как ответ? 
А я пока задам еще пару вопросов про статику и объект типа(их хранение в памяти и тд).

Comment: Мне кажется, я написал слишком мало для того, чтобы считать это полноценным ответом. Как комментарий это вроде бы ничего, а для ответа нужно было бы пересказать ту самую статью из MSDN.

Comment: @VladD ну прям всю статью и не надо,так..абстрактно :). И на удивление, материала действительно мало(как устроен VTable в C#, даже Рихтер об этом толком ничего не пишет).

Comment: @VladD я понял, VTable то по сути и нет. Есть обычная Method Table(таблица методов),а виртуальность уже устанавливается флагами NewSlot \ ReuseSlot в метаданных. Вот оно что...

Comment: Если вы разберётесь, может быть, вы и напишете хороший ответ? Всеми будет полезно.

Comment: @VladD да,пожалуй так и сделаю,но не уверен до конца в своей корректности. Пока задам еще один вопрос.

Comment: @CSharpUser кстати, в текущей реализации CLR все как-раз наоборот. в объекте лежит ссылка на его (его класса) method table. а уже в method table - на метаданные. Если решите копать глубже - вот вам ссылок: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx (windbg/sos/dumpmt) и http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/microsoft/clr%20memory%20tracing/sos%20docs/commands%5CDumpMT.htm

Comment: @PashaPash у меня в планах задать вопрос на тему "хранение объекта и объекта типа в CLR". Вот там уже хочу более детальнее рассмотреть эти нюансы. Так а я разве утверждал обратное,относительно таблицы методов ?:)   Объект в CLR имеет заголовок(Syncblk),и MethodTablePointer(это TypeHAndle по версии Рихтера),который и ссылается на объект типа этого экземпляра,в котором уже есть та самая таблица методов. Все верно,я не утверждал обратного :). Спасибо за статьи.

Comment: @CSharpUser не утверждали, просто это обычно является неожиданностью для тех, кто лезет во внутренности CLR :)