# Семантика работы\хранения UpCast"инга \ DownCast"инга в CLR

Tags: c#, память, clr, типы

Начнем с теории.
Допустим,имеется следующие классы:

```
class A{}
class B : A{}
class C : B{}
```

Далее,мы делаем **UpCast** :

```
A a1 = new C();
```

Будет ли следующее утверждение верным : объект ***a1*** является объектом типа C,и базовым классом для него является тип ***А*** (то бишь вверх по иерархии) !?

Далеко не уходя от кассы, представьте что добавили в код следующее:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method A invoked");
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public new virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method B invoked");
    }
}
class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method C invoked");
    }
}
```

Что будет выведено на экран ?
В первую очередь покажется,что тут все очевидно,и вывод выходе получим :

```
Method A invoked
Method A invoked
Method С invoked
Method C invoked
```

> Но на самом то деле,мы получим : Method A invoked Method A invoked Method A invoked Method C invoked

Исходя из этой логики,выходит что мое предыдущее высказывание не верное,и это значит,что все таки базовым классом для **C**,является **B** ?

---

Теперь перейдем к другой части вопроса.
К примеру имеем код:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //объект типа класса А
            A a = new A();
            //объект типа класса B
            B b = new B();
            //UpCast, который равен объекту "b"
            A a1 = b;
            //UpCast как отдельный объект
            A a2 = new B();
            //DownCast, который равен объекту "а1"
            B b1 = (B)a1;

            B b2 = a as B; // вернет Null, т.к. DownCast
            //без предварительного UpCast не возможен

            // B b2 = new A(); - невозможно из за безопасности типов

            //сравниваем b с а1,видим что типы идентичны.
            Console.WriteLine(b.GetType() == a1.GetType());
            //сравниваем а2 с а1,видим что типы идентичны.
            Console.WriteLine(a2.GetType() == a1.GetType());
            //сравниваем b1 и а1,видим что типы идентичны
            Console.WriteLine(b1.GetType() == a1.GetType());

            //Проверяем сами обьекты,вернет True
            Console.WriteLine(a1.Equals(b));
            //вернет False,но реализация этих объектов идентична
            Console.WriteLine(a2.Equals(a1));
            //Вернет True
            Console.WriteLine(b1.Equals(a1));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class A
    {
    }
    class B : A
    {
    }
```

[image: Примерный IL код(не все влезло)]

Так все же,что происходит за кулисами?
Как при ***UpCast"е*** \ ***DownCast"е*** ,два одинаковых объекта(точнее две ссылки,указывающие на один и тот же объект),имеют различную реализацию(да,да - это полиморфизм). За счет чего это достигается(то бишь,как CLR реализует эту модель поведения) и как примерно выглядит все это чудо-юдо в самой среде CLR ? Как выглядит "наследование" внутри **CLR** между типами?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По порядку:

> Будет ли следующее утверждение верным : объект a1 является объектом типа C,и базовым классом для него является тип А (то бишь вверх по иерархии) !?

Нет. Корректным утверждением будет следующее: объект `a1` является объектом типа C,и базовыми классами для него являются типы `B` и `А`.

Разница большая, поскольку каждый тип в иерархии наследования может привносить новые аспекты поведения.

Теперь дальше:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method A invoked");
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public new virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method B invoked");
    }
}
class C : B
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method C invoked");
    }
}
```

А данном примере сложно сказать, что именно хотел сказать автор этих строк с точки зрения бизнес-логики, но звучит это примерно так: класс `B` добавляет новый метод `Method`, но, к сожалению, он использует метод, имя которого уже есть в базовом классе. Но класс `B` хочет не "подменить" поведение метода из базового класса, а создать свой собственный метод, который ничего не имеет общего с методом базового класса, кроме имени.

Подобная практика приводит к неоднозначному поведению, поскольку теперь выбор метода определяется не только динамическим типом объекта (типом времени исполнения), но и типом переменной (типом, известным компилятору): если используется переменная типа `A`, то будет вызван метод из класса `A`. Если же тип переменной - это `B` или `C`, то будет использоваться другая ветка методов (ниже будет объяснение, почему это так).

Другими словами, с точки зрения метода `Method` существует две ветки: одна начинается типом `А` и им же и ограничивается, и есть другая полиморфная ветка, которая начинается в типе `B` и продолжается в наследнике - типе `С`.

Теперь немного о том, как это устроено в CLR.

Для каждого типа CLR хранит табличку с методами (Method Table), где каждая запись описывает отдельный метод - его сигнатуру и признак того, переопределяет ли данный слот метод из базового класса.

Когда вы объявили метод с приставкой `new` в классе `B`, CLR добавила "новый" метод в табличку, при этом пометила этот метод, как новый, не связанный с методом из базового класса. В случае же класса `С`, метод `Method` в табличке методово типа `C` помечен, как полиморфный, т.е. переопределяющий поведение непосредственного базового класса.

Теперь стоит сказать, как происходит разрешение метода во время исполнения: в случае вызова `a.Method` будет вначале определен статический тип переменной `a`, после чего в таблице методов будет найден метод `Method`. Если статический тип переменной - это `A`, то вначале будет просмотрена таблица методов типа `A`. И в этом случае CLR увидет, что этот метод виртуальный. После чего будет определен реальный тип объекта (например, тип `C`) и CLR посмотрит, а есть ли у этого типа переопределение метода, объявленного в типе `A`. CLR получит отрицательный ответ, поскольку тип `C` не переопределяет метод `Method`, объявленный в типе `A` (ведь этот тип переопределяет метод `Method` типа `B`).

Вот и получается, что результат разрешения имени метода у нас теперь зависит не только от типа времени исполнения, но и от типа переменной времени компиляции.

Comment: Насчет кода(в первом случае),это чисто синтетический пример,так сказать на понимание того,как все устроенно в CLR.
Такой вопрос: MethodTable хранится в типе,у каждого типа есть своя таблица методов. В случае если,у нас идет апкаст,то CLR просто рассматривает таблицу методов производного класса(точнее смотрит лексемы,которые сгенерировали метаданные,а затем уже проверяет флаги "ReuseSlot"(override),если такого нет,то возвращается к таблице базового и уже работает с ним? Так сказать in nutshell :)

И еще, статические методы никакого отношения не имеют к таблице методов,это так?

Comment: 1. В случае апкаста идет другой алгоритм просмотра таблицы методов. Начинается с типа переменной. И да, описан алгоритм правильно.
2. Для статических методов есть отдельная таблица методов.

Comment: Спасибо большое,Сергей! Читаю ваши статьи,и переводы.
Кстати,если у вас есть время,загляните сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607529/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-vtable-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5-clr

Comment: @CSharpUser Я обязательно отвечу. Это довольно сложный вопрос, так что дай мне плз день-полтора.

Comment: Да,без проблем :)